# Getting the smaller number inside a set of lists in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

I'm storing some data in mongoDB and one of the values I'm storing is stored in a list:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e69fa04250631b68443a6d"), "uts" : [ 1407623152, 1407623477 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e69f684250631b3d9645af"), "uts" : [ 1407622961 ] }
...
```

How can I get the smaller uts number between all the lists?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method is for as you are effectively manipulating the returned data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$uts" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": None,
        "uts": { "$min": "$uts" }
    }}
])
```

Returning the smallest value from all documents in the collection. Or to just get the smallest value per document, supply the original `_id` value for the grouping key:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$uts" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "uts": { "$min": "$uts" }
    }}
])
```

The [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator "de-normalizes" the array contents so that each entry effectively becomes a new document with all other values. The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator also does exactly what is says and "groups" documents by a given key. Here the [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) operator is used on the "uts" field to find the smallest value.

The [SQL to Aggregation Mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) document in the official documentation is a good place start for introduction to concepts.